# Laravel 5.4! FatalThrowable Error

Tags: php, laravel

trying to make a photo upload but It gives me the following error, even though it worked a while back! what is should I change? I am using larval 5.4

> FatalThrowableError Call to a member function getClientOriginalName()
>   on null

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    public function uploadPhoto(Request $request){

        $file = $request->file('pic');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $path ='public/img';

        $file->move($path,$filename);
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        DB::table('users')->where('id',$user_id)->update(['pic' => $filename]);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form? Failure to do so will not provide you the file you are expecting.

Comment: did you change the name for the input `<input type="file" name="pic">`

Comment: Looks like your upload did not came through. You need to check if `$request->file('pic')` returns `null` or `UploadedFile`. If null, you should throw an error.

However, something is wrong with your upload in HTML. Maybe show the upload Code.

Comment: looks like a problem with 'pic', have you got  {!! Form::file('pic', null) !!}?

Comment: `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` is a major hint that there's no file upload coming with that name. Sharing the controller code does not help since the problem is not here.

Comment: @Uzeyir Chalabi you should accept Tiger's answer if it solves your issue, ideally he was first to answer your issue

Comment: @CBroe how is this an "exact" duplicate of that post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Input` facade to check if your request has file object

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

$file = $request->file('pic');
if (Input::hasFile('pic')) {
    $filename = Input::file('pic')->getClientOriginalName();
   // .. rest of the code
}
```

Comment: why ... `$request` is the current request .. which is what the `Input` facade uses as its root

Comment: @lagbox i posted another possibility (not to duplicate the answer) as for using `$request` Tiger has already posted as an answer before me

Comment: you could use `Request`, `Input`, `$request`, `request()`, `app('request')` etc etc .. because they are all Request ... that was what i was pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your request the file does not exist, You may determine if a file is present on the request using the [`hasFile`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#files) method:

```
if ($request->hasFile('pic')) {
    //
}
```